# chmod if I am not root/file owner

Tags: linux, permissions

If I am not the file' owner or root, can I use chmod to change the file permission?

Assume I have group/write access to the file, e.g. 775

Comment: Related on [Unix.SE]: [When does chmod fail?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52519/50602)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a nutshell: No, you can't do that. Just for the plain reason that you could "steal" another user's file ([related source](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml)):

> Of course, only the owner of a file may use chmod to alter a file's permissions

There was another question on SO dealing with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965561/how-to-change-unix-permissions-when-i-dont-own-the-file-but-do-have-write-permis). The trick is to let `chmod` check if you're in the same group or have enough permissions in order to change that file's ownership and then run it as `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Basic answer is no, unless you have specific rights through the group you and the file is in.

Comment: Tell us more. If we are here, it's because we're interested in those specific rights.